# activestorage without time limited urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm not totally up to date with the latest developments in ActiveStorage. I'm using Rails 5.2.x and have a deep problem. The default URL generated for assets is a time limited call to

```
  {host}/rails/active_storage/blobs/{long-obfuscated-stuff-here}/{the-actual-file}
```

This method obviously had a clear use case in BaseCamp, but if you're using a CDN or Nginx/Apache  to serve assets directly from disk, it's as useful as a chocolate teapot because every request has to go through `rails/active_storage/blobs` and as it's a time limited unique url it can't be cached.

I see long threads on this problem trying to get core devs to accept PRs to fix this problem (e.g. [github issue 34477](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34477) )

And the problem might be fixed in the latest Rails 6. But I'm on Rails 5.2 and won't be upgrading in the near future.

So I need to know how to get the raw url for the base file so I can serve it directly from Nginx/Apache without going through the Rails stack.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would wait for a good solution to actually land in Rails, but you could always:

```
config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in = 99.years
```

Again, I'm not sure this is really the right thing to do but if you absolutely have to have permanent URLs it would work.

Comment: Actually I adopted a system based on an idea in  https://medium.com/sortlist-engineering/migrating-from-paperclip-to-activestorage-a-different-approach-4bffa2260e17

I put the storage directory under public/system then use an extra field `storage_url` in the blob record which points to the real data. Then I have a helper that converts that into a url in views. That means Apache/Nginx or CDN can go directly to the file without touching Rails.